# SonataAdminBundle batch update

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, batch-updates

I'm trying to create a feature in the admin dashboard, I have a `products` table and I want to create these batch features:

**Price Update**

Select one or more products, click on Price Update, show the products selected with the current prices, in a form with an input text called `new_price`, type on of these: %10 or -%10 or 5 or -5 [..], click on Update button and update the selected products with the new price

**Active**

This is almost the same as Price Update but using an input checkbox and de/activate the selected products

**Quantity Update**

Update the selected products quantity/stock

What I have tried is, override CRUDController, as described [here](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-2/doc/reference/batch_actions.html), but in the example it just show how to `merge` objects, overriding the `list__batch.html.twig` file adding an input option, it does not show how to create a custom template batch

Another thing that I have tried is to override `batch_confirmation.html.twig` like this:

```
{% extends base_template %}

{% block actions %}
    <li>{% include 'SonataAdminBundle:Button:list_button.html.twig' %}</li>
    <li>{% include 'SonataAdminBundle:Button:create_button.html.twig' %}</li>
{% endblock %}

{% block tab_menu %}{{ knp_menu_render(admin.sidemenu(action), {'currentClass' : 'active'}, 'list') }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="sonata-ba-delete">
        <h1>{% trans with {'%action%': action_label} from 'SonataAdminBundle' %}title_batch_confirmation{% endtrans %}</h1>

        {% if data.all_elements %}
            {{ 'message_batch_all_confirmation'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}
        {% else %}
            {% transchoice data.idx|length with {'%count%': data.idx|length} from 'SonataAdminBundle' %}message_batch_confirmation{% endtranschoice %}
        {% endif %}

        <div class="well well-small form-actions">
            <form action="{{ admin.generateUrl('batch', {'filter': admin.filterParameters}) }}" method="POST" >
                <input type="hidden" name="confirmation" value="ok">

                <input type="hidden" name="_sonata_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}">

                {% if data.action == "price_update" %}
                    <input type="text" name="new_price" value="BILLION" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="idx" value="{{ data.idx|json_encode }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="all_elements" value="{{ data.all_elements }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="{{ data.action }}">

                    # Show object rows
                {% else if data.action == "quantity_update" %}
                    # Show quantity_update object rows
                {% else if data.action == "de_activate_update" %}
                    # Show de_activate_update object rows
                {% else %} # delete batch action here!
                    <input type="hidden" name="data" value="{{ data|json_encode }}">
                {% endif %}

                # Don't know why this form is not displayed
                <div style="display: none">
                    {{ form_rest(form) }}
                </div>


                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">{{ 'btn_execute_batch_action'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}</button>

                {% if admin.hasRoute('list') and admin.isGranted('LIST') %}
                    {{ 'delete_or'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}

                    <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ admin.generateUrl('list') }}">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i> {{ 'link_action_list'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}
                    </a>
                {% endif %}
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Also I have to override the method `batchAction()` in `CRUDController` to manage the request

Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

I think your *Active* checkbox should simply be a editable boolean:

```
public function configureListFields(ListMapper $list)
{
    $list->add('active', null, array('editable' => true));
}
```

See the docs:
[Admin's documentation - Reference - Action List  (master) - 9.2. Customizing the fields displayed on the list page](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/action_list.html#customizing-the-fields-displayed-on-the-list-page)

Do the other batch actions have to be set per row or would you prefer to select multiple rows and then select your action AND your settings (Price etc.) on the footer of the list?

This is how I solved a batch action where I needed to an additional date field:
https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/2336#issuecomment-54800396

I will soon add a blog post where you can also see the actions inside the CRUDController.